# Turn off FireVault midway

Tags: macos

I am in the very beginning of the **Turn on FireVault** when I decided I did not want my disk encrypted.

What happens if I stop the process and/or shut the computer down before it is complete? Is it safe? Does it destroy or make files inaccessible?

Comment: Turn off FileVault

If you no longer want to encrypt your startup disk, you can turn off FileVault:

    Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Security & Privacy.
    Click the FileVault tab.
    Click Locked, then enter an administrator name and password.
    Click Turn Off FileVault.

Decryption occurs in the background as you use your Mac, and only while your Mac is awake and plugged in to AC power. You can check progress in the FileVault section of Security & Privacy preferences.